# How do I report content errors in an iBook?

Tags: books

How do I report errors in the content of an iBook that I've purchased? The feedback and problems reporting that I've found seems focused on getting a refund, not on repairing errors in the content.

(Note that the same errors are present in the Kindle editions of the book.)

Answer (score 1):

You can somehow try and contact the book publisher or you can try contacting [iTunes support.](https://www.apple.com/emea/support/itunes/contact.html)

As you say the issue is persistent I would recommend getting in touch with the book publisher by email.

Comment: I cannot see how iTunes support can help if the same errors are present in the kindle edition... Go for the Publisher & editor...

Comment: @SolarMike iTunes can help to look at the book formatting and make sure it is supported/guidelines are provided on how to fix it in future books

Comment: They won’t do that for the Kindle edition which is why it is a publisher & editor issue...

Comment: @SolarMike The OP mentioned iTunes contact so I mentioned it

Comment: the OP does not specify iTunes... just that the results found so far tend to be focused on getting a refund NOT correcting the errors, which is what the OP really wants to do. Now, given those errors are across two separate versions, then the producer & editor seem to be the most logical route for a suitable outcome or would you suggest Big Ears in ToyTown?